# Single screen parameter routing in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

If you have a screen with options, and a submit button. Is there a built in way to make the current parameter set that is selected available by sharing the link in angular 2?

For example:
If the following is selected on the page:

> UserType = Developer

I'd like the URL to read: `http://example.com/users?usertype=Developer.`

Currently the only approach I have for this is this:

```
        var route = this.url.path();

        if (this.url.path().indexOf("?") > -1) {
            route = this.url.path().substring(1, this.url.path().indexOf("?"));
        }

        this.router.navigate([route], {queryparams : { "usertype" : "Developer"}});
```

and then pulling it back out of the query parameters in the ngOnInit() method.

This seems messy, particularly the URL splitting, and I figure there must be a built in way to achieve this. Even if its just a better way to get that route url path.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need those methods. Just add this to whatever button you want to attach the params to:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/users']" [queryParams]="{usertype: 'Developer'}">developer</a>
```

That will route to: domain.com/users?usertype=Developer.

Then, on the new route, inside of ngOnInit, you can get the params easily like so:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((data) => {
     console.log(data);
   });
  }
```